# Differentiate between ip adress and DNS address in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dns, ip

How will i know a url adress is IP address or DNS address in ruby.

Example to clarify question:

IP Address: `http://74.125.236.72/`

DNS Address: `http://google.co.in`

Comment: Are those the only 2 types of input possible (i.e., valid IP or valid hostname)? Or is it also possible to get `random_string` as input, which should be classified as `invalid address` or something similar?. If it is the former you can use an approach similar to the one Robert posted to check if it is an IP address, and if not you know it's a hostname. Otherwise you would also have to check if it is a valid hostname.

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers By the time i need to do this i have already verified that the address is valid. I just need to know whether its an IP or DNS.

Answer (score 0):

Just check it manually?

```
 string =~ /\/\/[0-9.]+\/?$/
```

Comment: Note this regexp is not very strict, i.e., it will classify `'http://192...168.0000'` as an IP address. Perhaps the input will never be in an invalid format, but I would still suggest an improvement to only allow exactly 4 groups of 3 digits, i.e., `%r{^http://(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}}`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like below, I am thinking to solve this problem using [`IPAddr`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/ipaddr/rdoc/IPAddr.html):-

```
def dns_or_ip_addrs_check(address)
  addr = address[/http(?:s)?:\/\/([a-z0-9.]+)\/?/i,1]
  begin
    require 'ipaddr'
    IPAddr.new addr
    'ip address'
  rescue IPAddr::InvalidAddressError
    'dns address'
  end
end

dns_or_ip_addrs_check('http://74.125.236.72/') # => "ip address"
dns_or_ip_addrs_check('http://google.co.in') # => "dns address"
```